# ASP.NET Core MVC application insights stopped working after upgrade to .NET Core 1.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have one simple ASP.NET Core application I was working on back in December 2016. It worked just fine with application insights and telemetry.

Now after 4 months I wanted to pick up this work and started with upgrade from .NET Core 1.1.0 to 1.1.1. In this process package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` got updated from version `1.0.2` to version `2.0.0`.

This unfortunately caused my app to stop working, in particular I get this error:

```
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationInsightsJavaScript' and no extension method 'ApplicationInsightsJavaScript' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
    @Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)

Show compilation source
#pragma checksum "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "050a2afdfb4a44e17be72e76627a3d3a0d0b7d5a"
namespace AspNetCore
{
#line 1 "/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml"
```

Screen:

[image]

Upgrade from project.json to new csproj and using new Visual Studio 2017 doesn't help.

It looks like ApplicationInsightsJavaScript was basically removed from API. How do I enable javascript application insights then?

Comment: It's a major release, there are breaking changes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are breaking changes from ApplicationInsights 1.x to 2.x which are documented on GitHub [release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta1).

> - This release contains a rewrite of the SDK internals for better .NET
>     Core integration and initialization.
> - `UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry` is obsolete, the logic it used
>     to perform is handled automatically now and calls to this method
>     should be deleted from Startup.cs.
> - `UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry` is obsolete, exception
>     telemetry is handled automatically internally now. You should delete
>     calls to this method from Startup.cs otherwise you will get duplicate
>     exception telemetry reported.
> - The MVC dependency for the JavaScript
>     snippet has been removed so in order to include the JavaScript snippet
>     now you need to make the following changes:
>
>   - In _ViewImports.cshtml replace `@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration` with `@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet`
>   - In _Layout.cshtml replace
>       `@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)` with `@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)`

Comment: Just to add to this, when replacing the `ApplicationInsightsJavaScript` bit, you'll need to add `@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet` to the top of the layout file