# asp.net core - Application Insights : Live metric stream

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

According to the azure site, in order to do live metric stream you need to install the following package: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web

But this is not a .net core package, but it has dependencies on 4.x; Is there a .net core package somewhere?

From Azure's site:
[image]

But ther package listed is .Net 4.x and I can't find a .net core version.

Comment: Is that for debugging reasons, so you get the stats immediately instead of delayed? This can be enabled via `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(c => c.DeveloperMode = true);`

Comment: I already add application insights when building the host, so I can't add it though services; is there a way to pass this in the UseApplicationInsights call where I pass the key?

Comment: With key you mean instrumentation key? There are several ways to configure it. `InstrumentaitonKey` is also a property of the configuration object (passed as c in example above). Anther one is you pass a configuration section to it from the `IConfigurationRoot` object, then it sill be read from the appsettings.json file, i.e. `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights"));` and then add `{"ApplicationInsights":{"InstrumentationKey":"","DeveloperMode":true}}` to your appsettings.json

Comment: But the mention of `UseApplicationInsights` seems to imply you're using some older version. Maybe ASP.NET Core 1.x?  With Application Insights 2.x the APIs and registrations changed a bit. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684314/455493)

Comment: I think I have it completely backward: I thought UseApplicationInsights was the modern one and AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry was the old one; Am I wrong?

Comment: `AddXxx` methods typically configure dependencies for the built-in DI/IoC, whereas  `UseXxx` methods register a middleware (in `Configure` Method). But the `UseXxx` methods aren't required anymore with the 2.x Application Insights libraries.

Comment: At least when you're using VS2017 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 as pointed out [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta1) _Users of Visual Studio 2015 will need to make sure the following line is part of their WebHostBuilder chain in their Main method of Program.cs in order to get automatic configuration of their instrumentation key from appsettings.json:
.UseApplicationInsights()_

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification; I'll be moving the code to add and use the developer mode! thanks again!

Comment: Last I tried you needed a pre-release version of the Core App Insights library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions are a bit out-of-date, thank you for pointing to it!

Latest asp.net core AI SDK (2.2.0-beta3) has Live Metrics by default (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.2.0-beta3). We're planning to ship stable version soon.

Comment: I'll use that and report if I find bugs. Thanks

Comment: The last version until now is 2.4.1, but I still having the same legend in azure. Do you know if there's something else to do? I'm using net core 2.1